# Definition of cartesian product in topology

Tags: general-topology

In munkres' book, the general definition of cartesian product is the set of j tuples satisfying some conditions...... Which means that the cartesian product is a set of functions. How does this definition reduces to the old, familiar definition of the cartesian product of finite sets?(it is defined as a set of ordered pairs) i feel lost...any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't literally define an ordered pair to be a certain function, because functions are defined as certain sets of ordered pairs.

But. Say we define the ordered gizmo $[x,y]$ by saying $[x,y]=f$, where $f$ is a function with $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$. If one person defines $X\times Y$ to be a set of ordered pairs and another person defines $X\times Y$ to be a set of ordered gizmos there's an obvious simple canonical bijection between the two versions of $X\times Y$.

Basic principle regarding definitions: If you're defining "frammis" it doesn't matter what you say a frammis actually *is* as long as your framisses have all the properties frammisses are supposed to have. I mean a real number is a Dedekind cut? That's crazy - we know what a real number is, and that's not it. But the Dedekind cuts form a complete ordered field, so they "work" as a definition of real numbers. The definition of real numbers as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences also gives a complete ordered field. So it doesn't matter which definition we adopt.

Same here - the two definitions of $X\times Y$ give "isomorphic" objects, so which one is the real definition doesn't matter - all that matters about ordered pairs is that $(x,y)=(x',y')$ if and only if $x=x'$ and $y=y'$.

Comment: I thought about it again before reading your answer and realized i actually realized that i can regard ordered pairs as functions... So (1,2,3) ~ function x s.t x(1)=1, x(2)=2, x(3)=3 your answer gave me a new insight too. Thank you very much!

Comment: And you said "isomorphic objects" what kind of isomorphism are you talking about?

Comment: Was using the word "isomorphism" somewhat informally, meaning a map that preserves whatever properties are relevant in the relevant context. That's a little fuzzy, but it's clearly satisfied here - simply doesn't matter whether we say $X\times Y$ is the set of all $(x,y)$ or the set of all $[x,y]$.

Comment: All right. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Munkres defines on page 37 the cartesian product as follows:

> Let $\{A_1, \dots, A_m\}$ be a family of sets indexed with the set $\{1, \dots, m\}$. Let $X=A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_m$. We define the **cartesian product** of this indexed family, denoted by $A_1 \times \cdots \times A_m$, to be the set of all $m$-tuples $(x_1, \dots, x_m)$ of elements of $X$ such that $x_i \in A_i$ for each $i$.

To see that this definition is equivalent to the usual one, let's take $m=2$.

Then $A_1\times A_2$ is the set of ordered pairs (2-tuples) of elements of $A_1 \cup A_2$ where the first coordinate is in $A_1$ and the second coordinate is in $A_2$.

The usual definition would tell you that $A_1 \times A_2 = \{(x_1,x_2) : x_1 \in A_1$ and $x_2 \in A_2\}.$

The only way in which the Munkres definition differs from the usual definition is in specifying that the elements come from the union $A_1 \cup A_2$, but this is true in the usual definition too, because if the each coordinate is in the first or second set, then it is also in the union of both sets.